# I cannot edit instance of a nested structure in c

Tags: c, struct

My code does not work when trying to edit an instance of a nested structure. The code compiles successfully there is no error. It executes every line but it stops executing and does not finish executing when it reaches the second line below:

```
int numberOfProcess = 5;
shmem->pid_queue = createQueue(numberOfProcess);
enqueue(shmem->pid_queue, getpid());
```

These are the struct instances below:

```
SharedData *shmem;
Queue *queue;
```

Xcode gives the following warning:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS
```

My struct is below

```
typedef struct {
    int front, rear, size;
    unsigned capacity;
    int* array;
} Queue;


typedef struct {
        int shmInt;
        int timeSec;
        int timeNanosec;
        Queue *shmMsgSec_queue;
        Queue *shmMsgNanosec_queue;
        int items_in_queue;
        sem_t mutex;
        Queue *pid_queue;
} SharedData;
```

There are functions that manipulates queue shown below:

```
Queue* createQueue(unsigned capacity)
{
     Queue* queue = ( Queue*) malloc(sizeof( Queue));
    queue->capacity = capacity;
    queue->front = queue->size = 0;
    queue->rear = capacity - 1;  // This is important, see the enqueue
    queue->array = (int*) malloc(queue->capacity * sizeof(int));
    return queue;
}

int isFull( Queue* queue)
{  return (queue->size == queue->capacity);  }

int isEmpty( Queue* queue)
{  return (queue->size == 0); }

void enqueue( Queue* queue, int item)
{
    if (isFull(queue))
        return;
    queue->rear = (queue->rear + 1)%queue->capacity;
    queue->array[queue->rear] = item;
    queue->size = queue->size + 1;
    printf("%d enqueued to queue\n", item);
}


int dequeue( Queue* queue)
{
    if (isEmpty(queue))
        return INT_MIN;
    int item = queue->array[queue->front];
    queue->front = (queue->front + 1)%queue->capacity;
    queue->size = queue->size - 1;
    return item;
}

int front( Queue* queue)
{
    if (isEmpty(queue))
        return INT_MIN;
    return queue->array[queue->front];
}

int rear( Queue* queue)
{
    if (isEmpty(queue))
        return INT_MIN;
    return queue->array[queue->rear];
}
```

Comment: You haven't shown the code that sets up `shmem->pid_queue` - for all we know that's a dangling pointer. [mcve] please.

Comment: I am sorry @Mat   I have added it now

Comment: What is `isFull()`? What is the value of `numberOfProcesses`? If I would like to test your code, can you provide a small compilable reproducible code example with `main()` and all that has the problem? [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: shmem->pid_queue = createQueue(numberOfProcess); is not that the initiation? @KamilCuk

Comment: @omermuhit : It is but there is no context.  We have no idea what the value of `numberOfProcess` for example.  Morover "_ stops executing_" - exactly what are you observing?  Does it terminate or run indefinitely with no apparent output.  Have you used a debugger to see exactly what is happening?  What runtime diagnostics are issued, if any?

Comment: How do you initialize __`shmem`__? For all we know, `shmem` could be a null pointer, or not initialized. You seem to have latched onto that something with the code that deals with the `Queue` queue struct is wrong, completely ignoring, that the pointer `shmem`  simply could be invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Your *"second line below"* is

```
shmem->... = ...
```

Did you properly initialize `shmem` in the first place? For all we know it could be a null or invalid pointer.

For some reason you seem to have latched on, that your problem is with allocating `Queue` and not with where you assign the resulting pointer to. BTW, in C we don't cast the result of `malloc` (or any `void*` typed pointer for that matter) before assignment.